# How to make a website multilingual using VueJS and Strapi?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, strapi

I'm coding a website that uses VueJS 2 for frontend and Strapi for CMS and api management. What I am wondering here is that I am limited in terms of algorithms to make them work, hoping to get some help from experienced people who have done this before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the utility libraries for vue for localization.

[vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) or [vue-multilanguage](https://github.com/leonardovilarinho/vue-multilanguage).

Here is a list of [libraries](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#i18n) that support localization

Comment: I was aware of them but no tutorials with api and using Strapi-i18n.